# Pandas mutliIndex sort by group

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to keep values the same order (descending), but I am unable to group by index level 0 the following frame. The block with code 0512 should come together keeping descending order by code.

```
code   product                                        count
0510  あたたか新潟こしひかり　５ｋｇ　　　　　　　　　　       1
0511  キッコ−マン　味わいリッチ減塩しょうゆ　４５０ｍｌ       1
      ７プレミアム　国産果汁使用ゆずぽん酢　２００ｍｌ　       1
0512  キリン　生茶　５２５ｍｌ　　　　　　　　　　　　　       1
      キリンレモン　４５０ｍｌ　　　　　　　　　　　　　       1
      コカ・コーラ　い・ろ・は・す　もも　５５５ＭＬ　　       1
      サントリー　なっちゃん　オレンジ　４２５ｍｌ　　　       1
      サントリー　プレミアムボス　ブラック　４９０ｍｌ　       2
      サントリー　天然水南アルプス　２Ｌ　ケース　　　　       1
      サントリー　天然水南アルプス　２Ｌ　ペット　　　　       1
      サントリー　朝摘みオレンジ＆天然水　５４０ｍｌ　　       1
      大塚　ポカリスエット　９００ＭＬ　ペット　　　　　       1
      森永　ｉｎゼリー　エネルギーレモン　１８０ｇ　　　       1
      綾鷹　５２５ＭＬペット　　　　　　　　　　　　　　       2
      ７プレミアム　パイナップルサイダー　５００ｍｌ　　       1
      ７プレミアム　フルーツオ・レ　５００ｍｌ　　　　　       1
      ＧＡクラフトマン　ダークモカ　４４０ｍｌ　　　　　       1
      ＵＣＣ　職人の珈琲　無糖　９３０ＭＬ　ペット　　　       1
0513  アサヒ　オフ　５００ｍｌ×６　　　　　　　　　　　       1
      キリン　本麒麟　５００ｍｌ　　　　　　　　　　　　       1
      万上　濃厚熟成本みりん　１Ｌ　　　　　　　　　　　       1
      東村山純米酒　７２０ｍｌ　　　　　　　　　　　　　       1
0514  ブルボン　プチポテトコンソメ味　４５ｇ　　　　　　       1
      ロッテ　ガーナローストミルク　５０ｇ　　　　　　　       1
      ロッテ　グリーンガム　９枚　　　　　　　　　　　　       1
```

My code

```
data = df.groupby(['code','product']).size().reset_index(name='counts').set_index(['code','product'])
data1 = data.sort_values(by=['counts','code'], ascending=False).groupby(['product','code']).sum()
```

EDIT:

I could see that the second groupby put the code together but mess up the descending order of count per code as we can see for 0512.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a list to the ascending argument in the second line, like this:

```
data1 = data.sort_values(by=['counts','code'], ascending=[False,False]).groupby(['product','code']).sum()
```

Otherwise, it would take the default value which is True for "code" column.